# Why does number of Elasticsearch documents constantly automatically increase?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I just finished setting up an ES cluster with Kibana to monitor it. In Kibana I'm using *Legacy Collection* for Stack Monitoring.

When I go to the page "Stack Monitoring" in Kibana, I see that the number of documents is constantly increasing and probably adds about ~40 new documents every minute. Along with that the Disk Usage is also increasing as well.

The problem is I am not inserting any new documents into Elasticsearch. Here's a screenshot:

[image: kibana]

This is my `elasticsearch.yml` file:

```yaml
cluster.name: cool-cluster

node.name: ${HOSTNAME}
node.master: true
node.data: true

path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
path.data: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data

bootstrap.memory_lock: true

network.host: ip1
discovery.seed_hosts: ["ip1", "ip2", "ip3"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["ip1"]

xpack.security.enabled: true

xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: certificate
xpack.security.transport.ssl.client_authentication: required
xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.path: /etc/elasticsearch/certs/elastic-certificates.p12
xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.path: /etc/elasticsearch/certs/elastic-certificates.p12
```

And this is my `kibana.yml` file:

```yaml
server.host: "0.0.0.0"
server.name: "name"

elasticsearch.hosts: [ "http://ip1:9200" ]
elasticsearch.preserveHost: false

logging.dest: /var/log/kibana
logging.rotate.enabled: true
logging.rotate.keepFiles: 7

elasticsearch.username: "kibana"
elasticsearch.password: "password"
```

What is causing the number of documents (and disk usage) to increase? Is there anything I can do on my end to reduce it? Is this *normal* for the ELK stack, or did I misconfigure something?

Answer (score 1):

As you write, you have activated Stack monitoring. This means that a corresponding "*beat*" sends the monitoring statistics to your Elasticsearch instance, for displaying them in Kibana later on. And the individual measurements are stored as *documents* (like nearly everything in ELK Stack). That is why your number of documents continuously increases. You should be able to look up these documents under a corresponding Elasticsearch *index*.

Comment: That makes sense! Does Kibana delete these indices? Or does it get stored forever? And is there a way to reduce the amount of "beats" so that I don't consume as much storage space?

Comment: Thx. :) There is a concept called *rollover* in ES (see the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-rollover.html)) that should help you with getting rid of old documents in indices.

Comment: Regarding reducing the amount of "beats", resp. measurements, I guess this could be achieved by setting st like the `period` attribute - see [configuration reference of Metricbeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/metricbeat-reference-yml.html) as an example. Maybe a topic for another question if that doesn't help you. ;)